# Creating a column out of quartiles from another column

Tags: r

I want to make a new column out of quartiles from another column

```
df <- within(df, quartile <- as.integer(cut(df$x, quantile(df$x, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE)))
```

When I use this code I get

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, del, value = NULL) :    missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

df$x is numeric and doesn't have any NAs.

```
> sum(is.na(df$x))
[1] 0
```

Although in my df there are some NAs in some columns, I do not use those columns in the function mentioned above. I can't figure out where the problem is.

---

This function actually works.

```
df$Quartile <-cut(df$x,quantile(df$x),include.lowest=TRUE,labels=FALSE)
```

But the assigned variable *df$Quartile* doesn't appear in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `dplyr::mutate` to add a new column.

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
    mutate(q_col = cut(x, quantile(x), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE))
```

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb q_col
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     3
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     3
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     3
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     3
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1     2
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I type str(df) or View(df) I still can't find the variable. Even though the output of your function shows the variable in the console.

Comment: add ```dt <-``` before the line

Comment: Like this ```df %>% 
  mutate(q_col <- cut(x, quantile(x), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE))```?